# Use imported function with eval

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6, eval, ecmascript-2016

I call function like this :

```
import {required, maxLength} from 'utils/validation';
import sitesForm from './sites.json';
import productForm from './product.json';

var validateSite = {};
for(var group in sitesForm ) {
    var groupObj = sitesForm[group];
    for(var el in groupObj ) {
        console.log(eval('required'))
        validateSite[groupObj[el].name] = groupObj[el].rules.map(eval)
    }
}

//utils/validation.js
export function required(value) {
  if (isEmpty(value)) {
    return 'Champs requis';
  }
}
```

I got an error saying that required is not defined, in my json i got this array for the rules : 
"rules":["required"]

However the console.log(required) in the code shows : [Function: required]

Do you know why I can't use eval with required ?

Comment: Don't use `eval`.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well yeah, `eval` is going to return the result of the code inside. `eval('required')` is basically the same as `required`, and `required` is a function. What you should be doing is `eval('required()')`, but *really* you should be skipping `eval`! - `required()`. Why would you need it?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to call named functions, you should use indexer notation:

```
import validators from 'utils/validation';

validateSite[groupObj[el].name] = groupObj[el].rules.map(s => validators[s])
```

Comment: Oh thats great it works, did like this :

import * as validators from 'utils/validation';

Then I called this validateSite[groupObj[el].name] = groupObj[el].rules.map(s => validators[s])

Thanks